# How to create a 'boom' sound?

Tags: sound-design, sfx

[Jessica Jones Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWHUjuJ8zxE)

I like the 'boom' sound at the beginning of the trailer. how can I create it in ProTools?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Examples?

Comment: I mean that one right before the VO. That boom sound ranges around 100hz

Comment: Like the start to this (one of mine): https://soundcloud.com/james-oakwood/voices ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not currently running protools, so I can't tell you the exact plugins to use... BUT, to roughly approximate this sound, find a kick similar to the one at the beginning of the sound. Add to this a long reverb around 80-90% wet followed by a delay set to 1/4 (at 120 bpm) with a feedback long enough for it to echo around 5-7 times or whatever sounds good to you. After this, you will most likely need to EQ out highs and mids (down to somewhere around 300-400Hz) fairly drastically with a subtractive high shelf, perhaps 10dB or so. Also low cut anything under around 50Hz to keep sub frequencies under control.
This will never sound exactly like the clip since there are many variables, but it should get you in the ballpark. You can play around with reverb patches, EQ settings and different kicks to get something you like. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the reply! I'm new to sound design,I wonder what plugin can I use to create a kick/909 kick in Protools?

Comment: @Kei80, If you have BOOM drum machine plugin in pro tools, I believe it does some 909 style kits. You could always just find some free 909 samples online. There are plenty around. Try here:   https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=380004565452835&id=281867371933222

Comment: Thanks so much!I will try. I hope this will improve some impact and punchy SFX

Answer (score 0):

It just sounds like a 909 kick with reverb.